# Simple SINGLE checkbox validation in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I made it to page 3 on a google search, seems nobody uses single checkboxes anymore on their pages, and of course, the angular documentation (or any documentation) fails to mention how to validate one single frikkin checkbox.

just like this.

```
<form name="myForm" submit="mySubmitMethod()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="myModel.MyCheckbox"  required/>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.mycheckbox.$dirty && myform.mycheckbox.$invalid">submit</button>
</form>
```

So, in my form object, dirty never changes if i click it, and neither does invalid, regardless of the state. this makes no sense. Someone please help. I've been messing with this for a couple of hours now, and i'm unable to find anything on it.  Everyone is talking about groups of checkboxes.. I have one. I don't want to write a whole bunch of code for a single checkbox.

Comment: How are you setting the invalid state? What makes you think that dirty is never changed? I don't see anything wrong with your example (it's not too different from [Angular's own](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state)) so you might need to add an example snippet to show it not working.

Comment: How do you set the invalid state? the only thing i can find in the angular docs is this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

And I'm checking the dirty state by looking at the form object in chrome

Comment: If you aren't sure how to set invalid then I'm not sure why you are attempting to use it in your disabled state. Also, I don't believe you can use `required` on a checkbox field.

Comment: Other form fields have the $invalid state if they've been filled in. So i was looking for something similar, I'm guessing there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way.

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.mycheckbox.$dirty && myModel.MyCheckbox">submit</button>
```

`myModel.MyCheckbox` which is your model for checkbox will give `true or false` depend on your `checkbox selection` and disable your button according that.

So,in this way

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="!myModel.MyCheckbox">submit</button>
```

is also better one